# Change iframe from entered value in a textbox

Tags: php, iframe

I want to make a page that allows the user to enter his Minecraft name, the entered name will be changed in this link:

```
http://www.minecraft-skin-viewer.net/3d.php?layers=true&aa=true&a=0&w=330&wt=10&abg=330&abd=40&ajg=340&ajd=20&ratio=13&format=png&login=<NAME>&headOnly=false&displayHairs=true&randomness=708
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I know how to do it but don't know how to compose it to work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with jQuery.

For example, you have this html code:

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="button" id="dostuff" value="View your Skin!">
<hr>
<iframe width="290" height="433" id="SkinViewer"></iframe>
```

Where the tags used only contain relevant information for the script to work.

And the following jQuery code will work when the button is pressed. It create's the url with the value of the input field in it. And then sets the source of the iframe with the created url.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dostuff').click(function(){
        var url = 'http://www.minecraft-skin-viewer.net/3d.php?layers=true&aa=true&a=0&w=330&wt=10&abg=330&abd=40&ajg=340&ajd=20&ratio=13&format=png&login=' + $('#name').val() + '&headOnly=false&displayHairs=true&randomness=930';
        $('#SkinViewer').attr('src',url); 
    });
});
```

Keep in mind: for the jQuery to work you should load the jQuery library first!